# Node.js client certificate authentication on some paths only

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, x509

I have a `node.js` based web app that requires secure (`https`) connections from client. What I want is that on some paths client certificate authentication is required and on other paths not.

So for example. If user goes to https://www.example.com/main the server doesn't require client certificate authentication (and thus the browser won't ask anything). But if the user navigates to https://www.example.com/secure, then the client certificate authentication would be required (and thus the browser will pop up a dialog for selecting which certificate to use).

How can I make this happen. I am able to force client certificate authentication if I pass `requestCert:true` and  `rejectUnauthorized:true` to `https.createServer` options. The problem with this approach is that client certificate is required for every path.

Comment: Client certs are part of the SSL handshake; I'm not sure you can do what you want.

Comment: @Joe: That is what I was afraid of. But I have seen web sites that do that. First those apps display a page where they ask the user to insert smart card (where the client certificate is). When you press 'OK' the app redirects the user to another path in the same app that requires client certificate. At this point the browser displays a dialog for user to select the used certificate. So, maybe there is a way to somehow force a new handshake within the same connection?

Comment: I have a way to go around this problem, but I don't want to use it. One solution is to use two different listeners (different ports) within the same application. The other requires client certificate authentication and another not. The problem with this approach is that I then have to use non-standard port for the second one. That causes that some customers need to reconfigure their firewall to allow connections to that port.

Comment: @Jukka: Did you find an alternative to a separate listener?

Comment: Perhaps https://www.npmjs.com/package/client-certificate-auth -- although I haven't tested it myself.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this problem can be solved by setting up a reverse proxy/API gateway using Node.js package http-proxy-middleware which is compatible with express (the web server package we are using).

As shown in an example on homepage of the Node.js package, it could be done this way:
1.  Define the redirections for the UNAUTH and AUTH API as per convention used by http-proxy-middleware and use in next step.

2. Start an express HTTPS webserver on required port (say 3000) with http-proxy-middleware configured to act as reverse-proxy/API gateway. No need to set requestCert and rejectUnauthorized in https.createServer options.
3. Start an express HTTPS webserver on another port (say 3001) to serve UNAUTH API requests. No need to set requestCert and rejectUnauthorized in https.createServer options.
4. Start an express HTTPS webserver on another port (say 3002) to serve AUTH API requests. Set requestCert:true and rejectUnauthorized:true as https.createServer options.

The UNAUTH requests will be routed back/forth from 3000 to 3001 and AUTH requests will be routed back/forth from 3000 to 3002.

Answer (score 1):

I landed here because I am working on the same issue and will share the approach I'm taking. For endpoints that require the user to have authenticated using a valid cert I use a custom path appended to endpoints requiring the cert and verify that the user has authenticated using a cert if they are accessing any endpoint that follows that path (express app assumed). i.e.:

```
app.use('/api/cert', function(req, res, next){
    //validate that any token passed in the request was generated for a valid
    //cert login, otherwise reject request

    //pseudo-code
    if(isValidCertToken(req.authentication.token)) {
        next(); //this will pass it on to the correct endpoint in the /api/cert/[whatever] chain
    } else {
        req.status(401).send({error: 'invalid login, cert required'});
    }
});
```

This will require you to allow the user the ability to authenticate using certs by setting the `requestCert` flag to true, but will also allow other authentication methods if the user does not desire to use the "cert required" endpoints as long as the `rejectUnauthorized` is set to false when setting up the https connecton.

Comment: This still means the user is prompted with which certificate to choose on every path

Comment: Yes unfortunately. We avoid this by having a standalone SSO server using OAuth 2.0 that we redirect to for authentication.
Flow:
App->[user clicks login]->direct to OAuth 2.0 Server->[user prompted for cert]->[user validated based on cert]-> redirect to app with code to request token

OR

App->[user clicks login]->direct to OAuth 2.0 Server->[user prompted for cert]->[user selects cancel for no cert]->login screen displayed->[user authenticated with UN/PW]->redirect to app with code to request token

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by TLS renegotiation, but unfortunately this is not supported by TLS 1.3 so you have to disable it:

```
https
    .createServer(
        {
            // configure key, cert, ca,
            secureOptions: require('constants').SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_3,
        },
        function (req, res) {
            if (req.url.startsWith('/secure')) {
                req.socket.renegotiate(
                    {
                        requestCert: true,
                        rejectUnauthorized: true,
                    },
                    err => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('Renegotiation failed', err);
                            res.writeHead(500);
                            res.end('Internal Server Error');

                            return;
                        }

                        // handle secure content
                    },
                );
            } else {
                // handle main content
            }
        },
    )
    .listen(443);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i exactly understand what you want.. but based on my understanding if you are using express you can manage this thing by a simple middle-ware.. In that middle-ware you can track either request is coming from http or https through this

An HTTPS connection has req.connection.encrypted (an object with information about the SSL connection). An HTTP connection doesn't have req.connection.encrypted.

Also (from the docs):

With HTTPS support, use request.connection.verifyPeer() and request.connection.getPeerCertificate() to obtain the client's authentication details.

I hope this helps..

Comment: I am using Express framework with my application. All connections are already https. What I want is that some paths require a client to be authenticated with certificate and other paths not. I am using node 0.8.18 and it doesn't seem to have verifyPeer method in connection. getPeerCertificate method there is and it works as supposed (but it doesn't force the client certificate authentication ).